# Unit testing IBOutlet's properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ios6, gh-unit

I use `GHUnit`. I  want to test `IBOutlet`'s properties such as `isHidden`, `delegate`, etc.

I tried below code to test if `myView` is hidden :

```
- (void)testViewDidLoad
{
    // Call view on viewcontroller which will load the view if not loaded
    [testClass view];

    // Tests
    testClass.myView.hidden = YES;

    if (testClass.myView.isHidden) {
        GHTestLog(@"Hidden");
    }
    else {
        GHTestLog(@"Not Hidden");
    }
}
```

This always logs `Not Hidden`, whereas just before logging I set it  `hidden = YES`.

Why is this?

To test `delegate` property of an `IBOutlet` I tried below line :

```
GHAssertNotNil(testClass.textField.delegate, @"delegate is nil.");
```

It fails with `Reason : ((testClass.textField.delegate) != nil) should be FALSE.`

What is wrong?

**EDIT :**
Tried below code which does not work.

```
[testClass view];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                         bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
GHAssertNotNil(storyboard, nil);

// Tests
GHAssertTrue(testClass.myView.isHidden, nil);  // This fails
```

Comment: Do you have a test that verifies that `testClass.myView` is not nil?

Comment: @FlorianMielke You are right. `myView` is nil. But when I called `[testClass view];`, should not it get initialized? Or is there any way to initialize? The main point is it `IBOutlet` and hence `weak` property.

Comment: Are you using a XIB or storyboard for the interface?

Comment: @FlorianMielke storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing your views contained in a `UIStoryboard`, make sure that you've added your storyboard file to the test target.

I'd also suggest that you have a test that validates that your storyboard was successfully initialized like this:

```
- (void)testStoryboardShouldBeInitialized
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
    STAssertNotNil(storyboard, nil);
}
```

---

**Edit**

You first have to instantiate your view controller you'd like to test from your storyboard and then you can test your outlet:

```
UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerIdentifier"];
[controller view];
GHAssertTrue(controller.myView.isHidden, nil);
```

I'd also recommend to test (in a separate method) that your view controller is successfully instantiated. I'd also move the controller initialization into your setUp method - if necessary.

Comment: Tried it. Did not work. I have posted the exact code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the IBTextField on interface builder unable to find a defined textfield property.

That is you need to attach it or make connection of textfield to its property from interface builder.

(or may be because your `testClass` unable to point or give access to `textField`.)